# Where are internal functions in bytecode?

Tags: solidity, bytecode

I recently deployed a test contract on Ethereum that more or less just had a bunch of internal functions. On etherscan, decompling the bytecode I did not see these internal functions being listed. So... where are these internal functions in the bytecode? How are they referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using those functions in your code?

`internal` and `private` functions are not even included in the bytecode if you don't use them, calling them from another function, etc. Because they are only able to be invoked from within the contract itself, and if you are not calling them from the contract, then nobody can access them, hence, they don't need to be in the byte code and the compiler removes them.

Look at the following example:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Example{
  
    function f1() public pure returns(uint256) {
        return 531;
    }

    function f2() external  pure returns(uint256) {
        return 135;
    }

    function f3() internal pure returns(uint256) {
        return 123;
    }

    function f4() private pure returns(uint256) {
        return 321;
    }

}
```

Functions `f3()` and `f4()` will not be part of the bytecode because they are not used anywhere.

`f1()` selector: `c27fc305`

`f2()` selector: `9942ec6f`

`f3()` selector: `aaf05f3d`

`f4()` selector: `c3f90202`

You can calculate the selector by calculating the `keccak256` hash of the function signature. You can do that here: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

If we search these selectors in the bytecode, we will only find the selector for `f1()`, `c27fc305`, and `f2()`, `9942ec6f`.

Bytecode:

`6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060325760003560e01c80639942ec6f146037578063c27fc305146051575b600080fd5b603d606b565b604051604891906095565b60405180910390f35b60576074565b604051606291906095565b60405180910390f35b60006087905090565b6000610213905090565b6000819050919050565b608f81607e565b82525050565b600060208201905060a860008301846088565b9291505056fea2646970667358221220a02ffe53f2d3c8f10d26cf91484ade3ccaa0f3f7eae7489915ca4fe66b5a67d064736f6c63430008110033`

If you call an `internal` or `private` function from another function inside the contract, they still don't get a selector assigned because you cannot invoke them from outside anyways. But they are included in the bytecode and other functions call them directly.

Look at this example:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Example{
  
    function f1() public pure returns(uint256) {
        return f3();
    }

    function f2() external  pure returns(uint256) {
        return f4();
    }

    function f3() internal pure returns(uint256) {
        return 123;
    }

    function f4() private pure returns(uint256) {
        return 321;
    }

}
```

It's bytecode is:

`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`

It still doesn't contain the `f3()` and `f4()` selectors, because there's no need to since they are not able to be called from outside. But the bytecode is longer now, it includes those functions.

You can try decompiling both bytecodes and check youself here: https://ethervm.io/decompile